# Unable to ssh into app: "Application 'prod' not found" but it is in the apps list. How can I fix this?

Tags: ssh, openshift

```
$ rhc apps
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
dev @ http://
... 
prod @ http://

$ rhc ssh prod
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
Application 'prod' not found.

$ rhc ssh --app dev
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
Application 'dev' not found.
```

I'm not sure what else to say. I don't want to delete my ssh keys because I use them elsewhere; plus the error doesn't seem to be related to ssh keys.

I have found that I can log in to apps that I created but not apps that are shared with me. Even when using the ssh address provided for that app (`rhc ssh 565fc20989f5cfec5f111012@...`):

```
$ rhc ssh 565fc20989f5cfec5fddfd12@prod-xyzdomain.rhcloud.com
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
Application '565fc20989f5cfec5fddfd12@prod-xyzdomain.rhcloud.com' not found.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your application is "`prod-myapp.rhcloud.com`" your application name is actually just "prod".  The naming scheme is `<application name>-<domain>.rhcloud.com`.

So the command to ssh into your application would be "`rhc ssh prod`" or "`rhc ssh prod -n myapp`" if the application **is not in your default domain**.

Comment: When I list apps I get entries like `XYZ @ http://...` and `ZYX @ http://`. When I try to log in to XYZ with `rhc ssh XYZ` it fails. It seems like I'm already doing what you are suggesting. I can log in to an app I created but I can't log in to one that I have shared access to.

Comment: I clarified my post a bit.

Comment: Ah, the not in default domain part was the issue. Thanks. There's nothing in the docs about that on the SSH page.